# Is there support for UpdateByQuery in Elasticsearch Sink Connector or can someone direct me to any such customized sink connector for elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka-connect

Consider below scenario

Database
Table1,Table2 -->(1)

--> (1) Debezium-Source-Connector --> Table1Topic, Table2Topic ----->(2)

--> (2) KStream (will convert and rename **Table1Topic** and **Table2Topic** to **ProcessedTopic**.
basically kstream will process **Table2Topic** data only and add below fields without any id field
in payload(updateByQuery, updateScriptSource,targetIndex) and **Table1Topic**
will be just renamed to **ProcessedTopic**.
Here **Table2Topic** have information which needed to be updated in target index
in our case **Table1Topic** data is primary data with document id which we want to save
in elastic search and **Table2Topic** data will be merged on top of **Tale1Topic** index by elasticsearch by _update_by_query)

updateByQuery <--- will be used to prepare query field for "_update_by_query" request

updateScriptSource <--- will contain update data for script source in "_update_by_query" request

targetIndex <--- contain target index name

Ex:
{
"script": {
"source": updateScriptSource,
"lang": "painless"
},
"query": updateByQuery
}

Note: Kstream is my personal implementation to process topics

(2)---> ProcessedTopic ---> (3)ElasticSearch-Sink-Connector --->(4) ElasticSearch

I want to achieve above scenario.
If there is already some similar implementation available then could someone please direct me.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks